# Sending a simple TCP message using Netcat

Tags: netcat

I am trying to use netcat to send a simple message over TCP, e.g. I want to send the digit 1.

So I understood that I write the following in the terminal, after installing netcat

`netcat [ip-address] [port]`

But how do I specify the message to be sent? i.e. where to I write `"1"` ?

Answer (score 74):

Create file `something.txt`, content of file is 1

```
netcat [ip-address] [port] <something.txt
```

At destination you must have something to listen to this.

or

Server:

```
netcat -l -p [port]
```

to listen to the connection

Client:

```
netcat [server-ip-address] [port]
```

After connection is establish on cilent simple type
`1` and hit `enter`

Comment: Submitted an edit changing the useless `cat` command to redirection to `echo`. I use this method to send string data to remote machines that are operating as one for greater bash multi-tasking.

Comment: +1 for the server tip! That's very cool, thanx!

Comment: thnks, this is working for me

Comment: Just wanted to not that -p is not mandatory, port can be specified directly as non-optional argument

`netcat -l [port]`

Answer (score 36):

I use:

```
echo text | netcat host port
```

So you would just need to run this:

```
echo 1 | netcat localhost 12345
```

Comment: or  
`netcat <host> <port> <<< 1`